# Custom UIActivityViewController with backgroundColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

How can I set color of bottom view with all elements of `UIActivityViewController`?

My current implementation changes color for all view -

```
CopyLink *copyLink = [[CopyLink alloc]init];
copyLink.delegate = self;

self = [self initWithActivityItems:@[emailActivity] applicationActivities:@[copyLink]];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

self.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do... Are you trying to change the background color of the UIActivityViewController?

Comment: Your question's written very unclearly, to be honest.

Comment: He/She is trying to change the color of the bottom row of activities. The answer is, you can't do this. At least not with the API provided. You can probably accomplish it by digging into the actual view hierarchy of the `UIActivityViewController` and finding the background view for the bottom row (if it is even separate, it might just be the same view with a divider line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, the UIActivityViewController is supposed to take form of an overlay sheet, I doubt you can even access the view of it let alone its background colour, You may have to create a custom Subview and then use that as the subview

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to use `UIActivityViewController` :

```
-(void)doStartStopSpinner
{
    if (![spinner isAnimating])
    {
        spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        spinner.center = self.view.center;
        spinner.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.6];
        [self.view addSubview:spinner];
        [spinner startAnimating];
    }
    else
    {
        [spinner stopAnimating];
        [spinner removeFromSuperview];
        [viewUpgradePro removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: You've given an answer for `UIActivityIndicatorView`, but the question is about something else.